# Python: Convert list [a,b,c,d] to [ [a,b],[b,c],[c,d] ]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a thousand numbers in a list like this:

```
A=[1,2,3,4]
```

I want to covert this in the following format:

```
desired_A=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

#### Code:

```
desired = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(A, A[1:])]
```

#### Test Code:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
desired = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(A, A[1:])]
print(desired)
```

#### Result:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one neat list comprehension. You are creating a new list where for each element in A, the new list has a list that contains that element and the element after that element.

```
desired_A = [[A[i], A[i+1]] for i in range(len(A)-1)]
```